# Can I run Mindscape Web Workbench's SCSS -> CSS conversion on SCSS files without a csproj?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sass, visual-studio-extensions

I've opened a SCSS file in Visual Studio 2012 that isn't part of a csproj or VS solution (right-click SCSS file -> Open with.. -> select VS2012 devenv.exe).

When I save changes to Styles.scss, I'd expect Mindscape Web Workbench to re-compile the SCSS and write the changes to the Styles.css in the same directory. Works fine when saving SCSS files in a VS solution/csproj.

I know there are alternatives like Compass, the SASS Ruby Gem, assorted Sublime Text 2 build packages, etc, but I haven't got those installed and it seems like Mindscape should be able to handle this. Can one solitary SCSS-to-CSS file transform be done in VS2012 with Web Workbench?

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using Mindscape to help with Sass, it's a bit overkill. There's a well-supported extension that is much more lightweight and under development.

https://github.com/darrenkopp/SassyStudio

Sass is a gem as well...and you've got to watch the file for it to be compiled regardless, so I just open the file in VS after having initialized the sass engine to start watching the project and on saving the file, it runs the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Without the csproj it is not really possible.

First of all, because csproj groups files. You need that to use .scss and .css files as one group.

Secondly, csproj defines what action to apply to file on build/save.

Although, technically it is possible to do some action without csproj, but Mindscape Web Workbench does not offer that.